# htaccess redirect to new page structure within the same domain + https and www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have designed a new website and I'm going to replace the old one, but I have changed the final URLs of each page. For example I have changed:

mydomain.com/contact to mydomain.com/contact-us
mydomain.com/about to mydomain.com/about-us
etc...

Additionally I want to redirect http -> https and always add www.
Here is what I have. What is wrong with this code?

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 /old-page/ /new-page/
```

I used Wordpress (own theme) if that affects anything.
Thank you

Comment: _“What is wrong with this code?”_ - you tell us - by giving us a _proper_ problem description first of all! What _exactly_ is not working as you expected it to?

Comment: (What is definitively wrong, is the _order_ in which you are attemtping those things. You need to do your external redirects, before the internal rewrites of the WP routing kick in.)